# Pase de parametros JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Intento hacer una función en JavaScript que reciba dos parámetros, funciona perfectamente con un solo argumento pero cuando intento pasar 2 deja de funcionar y no encuentro la falla alguna idea ?

Así llamo a la función

```
    out.print("<a href='#'  onclick='confirmDelete('"+id+"','"+ext+"');'>Eliminar</a>");//Opción a eliminar
```

Función javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmDelete(idCat,ext) {

var id=idCat;
var extencion=ext;
if(confirm("¿Desea eliminar la categoria?"+id+extencion)) {

//document.location.href= '../EliminarCategoria?idCat='+id+'';

}

} 
</script>
```

Comment: Por favor provee el código JSP completo. Además, te recomiendo evitar el uso de scriplets puesto que dificulta la lectura del código, por ende dificulta el mantenimiento.

Comment: gracias  por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando comilla simple `'` tanto en el atributo `onclick` como en los parametros.

Debería estar formateado uno con comilla doble y el otro con comilla simple.

```
out.print("<a href='#' onclick=\"confirmDelete('"+id+"','"+ext+"');\">Eliminar</a>");
             //                 ^ .. aqui y . ........... ... aqui  ^
```

Como ves, debes escapar la comilla doble para que java sepa que es parte del string y no el final del mismo. Es decir `"... onclick=\" ... \" ... "`.

Comment: Gracias me funciona perfecto